# How to display the control center on iOS without AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, mpremotecommandcenter

In my iOS app, I use a third party library to play music (I use the [JUCE framework](https://juce.com/)).

Now I would like to show my users the control center like the one below, so they can interact with the music player from the lock screen:

[image: Remote control center]

To achieve that, I use the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`, as explained [here](https://www.threadsafe.xyz/2020/12/mpremotecommandcenter-and.html).

My problem is: that control center displays correctly only if I use the `AVAudioPlayer` class (or similar) to play music…

Is it possible then to display and use that control center to control music played with a third party library?

Thanks.